# Is it possible to access the UV index based on city in pyowm?

Tags: python, project, weather, openweathermap

I know it is possible to access the UV index as         `owm.uvindex_around_coords(25.2048, 55.2708)` however I can't seem to find a function call that can a city as input (e.g. 'London, GB').

Answer (score 0):

No, the [API](https://openweathermap.org/api/uvi) for current/forecast/historical UV could be called only with coordinates